# An if statement returns a different variable on each branch, how can I assign to that variable using only one <- operator?

Tags: r, if-statement, variable-assignment

Consider

```
if(sample(2, 1) == 1) a <- 5 else b <- 5
```

This is repetitive. Is there any way to not have to write `<- 5` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `assign` -

```
assign(if(sample(2, 1) == 1) 'a' else 'b', 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `list2env`

```
list2env(setNames(list(5),  c('a', 'b')[sample(2, 1)]), .GlobalEnv)
```

-checking

```
> a
[1] 5
```

Comment: I must admit, until now I didn't know that `list2env` had more than one argument.